# Unable to clear cache in EF

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Iam facing a problem while using factory model in MVC.
As i update and try to display the data from the same table, the update is being performed in the database but the updated data is not being fetched from the database.
I feel that it is fetching the data from the Entities and displaying the data.
I used Modelstate.clear() outputcache etc., but none of it worked.

code used:
For Update:

```
public virtual void Update(TObject TObject)
        {
            var entry = Context.Entry(TObject);
            DbSet.Attach(TObject);
            entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
        }
```

calling Update method in my service and saving changes:

```
Registry.RepositoryFactory.GetUsersRepository().Update(userobj);
            Registry.Context.SaveChanges();
```

Fetching data after save:
Select:

```
 public virtual IQueryable<TObject> All()
        {
            return DbSet.AsQueryable();
        }
```

I am able to update in the database, but as it try to retrieve the data immediately from the same table it is not hitting the database, i think it is fetching the data from the cache.

Any pointers are welcome.

Thanks in advance,
 Girish.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. It helps if you add the smallest sample of code that demostrates your issue. With only text it is hard to provide an answer.

Comment: `DbSet.AsQueryable();` does not fetch anything. Also, why do you want to fetch data you just saved?

Comment: I want display the status of the users. If inactivate an user, he should be shown Inactive in my UI. So, I update the Users table and fetch the updated data. Why wont DbSet.AsQueryable(); fetch anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess that you are re-using the same EF Context object for both the Update and the Select. If the Context is not disposed of between these events you will end up with a stale context and data will be returned from the EF cache.

Make sure you are disposing of the EF context between calls with the best practise being to surround it in a Using statement. An alternative to this is to call Refresh() on the Context (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462620/entity-framework-data-context-not-in-sync-with-database) question). You'll still need to dispose of the context at some point because otherwise it will continue to grow and your application will get slower and slower.

I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18737340/asp-net-insert-to-database-not-updating/18737757#18737757).

Comment: You are absolutely correct. Please guide me how to use the Refresh method i.e., where should i use it?

Comment: This link (refered from the question I referenced about it)  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896255.aspx provides sample code. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed the link provided by Damon, the problem is that Refresh occurs. But it is taking few seconds(2 or 3). The page has to load immediately.

The solution that has worked for me is that, while fetching the data from the repository, i am setting the entity using Set. And then i used Refresh method before fetching the data.

Code used:

DbSet set = ((DbContext)Context).Set();
((IObjectContextAdapter)Context).ObjectContext.Refresh(System.Data.Objects.RefreshMode.StoreWins, set);
return DbSet as IQueryable;